# ms crm JumpBarAlphabetOverride

Tags: web-services, customization, dynamics-crm-2015

to customize the GridJumpBar, I believe I need to use this command :

```
Microsoft.CRM.SE.OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.exe Update MyOrganization JumpBarAlphabetOverride "NewAlphabetBarDefinition"
```

but I cannot get the 'OrgDBOrgSettingsTool.exe' to work, I have 'MS CRM 2015 On prem' and I cannot set the config settings, I think,

I get this error :

```
Error occurred in OrgDBOrgSettings and the error details are Metadata contains a
 reference that cannot be resolved: 'mycrm.crm.com/.../Disc
overy.svc?wsdl&sdkversion=7.1'.Unable to connect to the remote server
```

this is the address, which I browse to my crm, and my account is system admin on the server machine:

http://localhost/TEST/

how should I overcome this, can anybody give me some direction on customizing the config file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not figure out what is the problem, when I managed to even fill the `.config` file, I got stock with the authentication, even though I was doing all the job with an Administrator account on the CRM Server,

anywho

I found this [Ms. CRM 3rd party Soloution](https://orgdborgsettings.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=How%20to%20use%20the%20editor&referringTitle=Home), which works like a charm